# Porque meu método sincronizado não funciona como o esperado?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thread, multithreading

Eu tenho uma classe chamada `GerenciadorServerSocket`:

```
@Service
public class GerenciadorServerSocket {

    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> portasUsadas = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(new ArrayList<>());

    public boolean isPortaUsada(Integer port){
        return this.portasUsadas.contains(port);
    }

    public void addPorta(Integer port){
        this.portasUsadas.addIfAbsent(port);
    }
}
```

Quando minha aplicação é levantada, via spring boot, ela é injetada na minha classe `SocketHandler`, que é injetada na minha classe de inicialização chamada `ApplicationRunnerAdapter`:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationRunnerAdapter implements ApplicationRunner{

    private final TerminalService terminalService;
    private final SocketHandler socketHandler;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationRunnerAdapter(TerminalService terminalService, SocketHandler socketHandler){
        this.terminalService = terminalService;
        this.socketHandler = socketHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args){
        List<Terminal> terminais = terminalService.findAllByStatusAndEmpresaStatus(TerminalStatus.ATIVO, EmpresaStatus.HOMOLOGACAO);
        terminais.forEach(terminal -> new Thread(new SocketServerChannel(terminal, terminalService, socketHandler)).start());
    }
}
```

Quando o Runner está pronto, será executado o método `run`, que busca uma lista de objetos do banco de dados para criar vários servidores sockets.

Classe `SocketServerChannel`:

```
public class SocketServerChannel implements Runnable {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private final TerminalService terminalService;
    private final SocketHandler socketHandler;
    private final Terminal terminal;

    public SocketServerChannel(Terminal terminal, TerminalService terminalService, SocketHandler socketHandler){
        this.terminal = terminal;
        this.terminalService = terminalService;
        this.socketHandler = socketHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            AsynchronousServerSocketChannel serverChannel = createSocketChannel();
            while(serverChannel != null && serverChannel.isOpen()){
                Future<AsynchronousSocketChannel> acceptFuture = serverChannel.accept();
                if (acceptFuture != null){
                    AsynchronousSocketChannel socketChannel = acceptFuture.get();
                    logger.info("Chegou conexão socket. Ip: "+socketChannel.getLocalAddress().toString()+"  "+socketChannel.getRemoteAddress().toString());
                    new Thread(new SocketClientChannel(getProtocolo(this.terminal), getPort(this.terminal), socketChannel, serverChannel, socketHandler, terminalService)).start();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private AsynchronousServerSocketChannel createSocketChannel() throws IOException {
        Integer port = getPort(this.terminal);
        if (port == null || socketHandler.isPortaUsada(port)){
            logger.error("Porta "+port+" já está em uso! Favor, utilizar outra.");
            return null;
        }
        socketHandler.addPortaUtilizada(port);
        logger.info("Criando conexão socket na porta: "+port);
        return AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open().bind(new InetSocketAddress("10.1.1.150", port)); //TODO tocar host name
    }

}
```

Nessa classe é onde vem o meu problema, pois alguns objetos podem vir com portas repetidas e ele não pode mais abrir uma conexão socket para aquela mesma porta.
Eu tenho uma classe chamada `SocketHandler`que lida com todas as operações de escrita do socket, e nela também, eu verifico se a porta já está em uso ou não.
Essa classe possui todos os métodos sincronizados e ela é instanciada apenas uma vez, na inicialização do sistema, lá na minha classe `ApplicationRunnerAdapter`.

Classe `SocketHandler`:

```
@Service
public class SocketHandler implements SocketCallBackHandler {

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean isPortaUsada(Integer porta) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(porta);
        return this.gerenciadorServerSocket.isPortaUsada(porta);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void addPortaUtilizada(Integer porta) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(porta);
        this.gerenciadorServerSocket.addPorta(porta);
    }
}
```

Como pode ser visto, os métodos estão como sincronizados, ou seja, várias threds esperariam o bloco ser executado para assim então, pode executar.
Acontece que, mesmo com essas verificações, ele está tentando criar portas que já estão em uso.

Onde eu estou errando?

Comment: Você já experimentou tornar sincronizado o método `createSocketChannel()`?

Comment: Não sei se faria sentido pois o `createSocketChannel()`está dentroda prórpia thread, então acredito que ficaria syncronizado dentro de cada thread, e não compartilhado. Certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temos uma situação multitarefa:

```
terminais.forEach(terminal -> new Thread(new SocketServerChannel(terminal, terminalService, socketHandler)).start());
```

Mas a forma de tratar essa situação, torna esse código em uma bomba relógio:

```
private AsynchronousServerSocketChannel createSocketChannel() throws IOException {
        Integer port = getPort(this.terminal);
        if (port == null || socketHandler.isPortaUsada(port)){
            logger.error("Porta "+port+" já está em uso! Favor, utilizar outra.");
            return null;
        }
        //-->estopim!!! acenda o pavio da bomba aqui<--
        socketHandler.addPortaUtilizada(port);
        logger.info("Criando conexão socket na porta: "+port);
        return AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open().bind(new InetSocketAddress("10.1.1.150", port)); //TODO tocar host name
    }
```

Entre a chamada de `socketHandler.isPortaUsada(port)` e `socketHandler.addPortaUtilizada(port)` o sistema operacional pode agendar a thread para executar em outro momento, ou as threas foram executadas em paralelo, e chegaram na mesma conclusão.

Isso quer dizer que mil coisas podem ter acontecido, e a condição que tinha sido estipulada, já não é mais verdadeira.

Para resolver o problema, é necessário um método em que `isPortaUsada` e `addPortaUtilizada` sejam uma operação atômica.

```
synchronized boolean addPortaUtilizadaAtomicamente(Integer port) {
    if(isPortaUsada(port)) { return false; }
    addPortaUtilizada(port);
    return true;
}
```

Metaforicamente, torne o seu código numa bomba atômica.

Comment: Acabei chegando a essa mesma conclusão, irei colocar sua resposta como a correta. Mas porque você acha que o código seria uma bomba relógio?

Comment: Quando existem bugs no manejo de threads, o programa pode funcionar corretamente na primeira vez, quando o programador interage com o programa. O bug costuma aparecer quando o usuário começa a usar o programa. Resumindo, é questão de tempo.

Comment: Ah. entendi. Felizmente, peguei o problema em tempo de desenvolvimento. Em relação ao uso da sincronização dos métodos, você acha que ficou bem arquitetado? No caso, não terá problemas de concorrencia?

Comment: Eu moveria a sincronização para a classe `GerenciadorServerSocket`, ela que tem o papel de cuidar das portas. Quanto a `SocketHandler`, eu removeria os métodos `isPortaUsada`,`addPortaUtilizada`, e adicionaria o método `getGerenciadorServerSocket()`, porque isso nem é problema dele, então não faz sentido ele ficar intermediando tudo.